# 100 Malicious / Spam mail in postfix relay everyday

Tags: linux, postfix

I use a Linux VPS as postfix relay and for several days I get through at least 100 mails like this "msg1473899@DomainName". I have two websites hosted on the server and each spam uses two domain names.

How to detect the problem?
and how to protect themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no simple, one-size-fits-all solution to spam.  We won't be able to give a plug'n'play (or copy'n'paste) solution here. The best advice I can give is to read some of the howtos in the UCE/Virus section of the [postfix docs page](http://www.postfix.org/docs.html).

Personally, I found `postscreen` to give me the best results relative to the time invested.  It's easy to setup and blocks probably 80%-90% of all spam.

Comment: Hi Tarleb,
I chose another solution with MailChimp and Mandrill to send mails since my domain name. With this solution, I don't have install postfix. I'll try later postfix and postscreen.